# Dense subset in Hilbert space given by the span of an orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$. Let $X$ be the set of all finite sums $\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \lambda_i e_i$. Show that $X$ is dense by showing that $X^{\perp}=\{0\}$.

Now

$
X^{\perp}=\{y:y \in H \text{ and } (\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \lambda_ie_i,y)=0\}.
$

How do I show that $y=0$ is the only solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write

$$y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ie_i\implies \forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;0=\langle y,e_n\rangle=a_n\ldots$$